# Local variable referenced before assignment in Python

Tags: python, function, variables, scope

```
Truel=""
count = 0
finle_touch=False #true after it find the first 3 upperletter

# check if there is 1 lower letter after three upper letter
def one_lower(i):
    count=0
    if i == i.lower:
        finle_touch=True
        Truel=i

# check for 3 upper letter
def three_upper(s):
    for i in s:
        if count == 3:
            if finle_touch==True:
                break
            else:
                one_lower(i)
        elif i == i.upper:
            count +=1
            print(count) #for debug
        else:
            count ==0
            finle_touch=False

stuff="dsfsfFSfsssfSFSFFSsfssSSsSSSS......."
three_upper(stuff)
print(Truel)
```

So I have a lot of string on 'stuff' and  I like to find 1 lowercase letter that's surrounded by 3 uppercase letter.

But when I run this code I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\mypy\code.py", line 1294, in <module>
    three_upper(stuff)
  File "C:\Python33\mypy\code.py", line 1280, in three_upper
    if count == 3:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment
```

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Due to this line `count +=1` python thinks that `count` is a local variable and will not search the global scope when you used `if count == 3:`. That's why you got that error.

Use `global` statement to handle that:

```
def three_upper(s): #check for 3 upper letter
    global count
    for i in s:
```

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/functions.html):

> All variable assignments in a function store the value in the local
>   symbol table; whereas variable references first look in the local
>   symbol table, then in the global symbol table, and then in the table
>   of built-in names. Thus, global variables cannot be directly assigned
>   a value within a function (unless named in a global statement),
>   although they may be referenced.

Comment: thanks, i though that define the var outside of the function will solve this problem. so every time i will use global var in function i will have to define it as global?

Answer (score 2):

It is actually better to use nonlocal in this case. Use global as sparingly as possible. More information about nonlocal here  [docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal)